# Auth logout in cakephp 3x with plugin ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I want destroy token but that not working:

> $this->Auth->logout();

Can you help me. Thank all

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
```

Comment: I tried But that return old token when login. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jwt is not stored on server. To logout you just delete the token on the client.
If you want to invalidate before it exprire, you have to manually insert token to the database and on every request check if token is invalidated or not